# Why it show python missing?

Tags: kubuntu, python, ansible

Python used to work with ansible. After reinstalling ansible, it looks like python is missing. Do you think so? Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9KjT.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pc04m.png)

Comment: does `python3` work?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu has completed it's migration from Python2 (the `python` command) to Python3 (the `python3` command).

Most `python` commands still work if you simply substitute `python3`.

Python2 is no longer included with a stock install of Ubuntu flavors, but is trivial to install of you want it: `sudo apt install python`. (Indeed, this was one of the options suggested in your screenshot)